# Why aren't parts of company ads separately clickable?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I saw this ad, and was impressed that it seemed to have linked in other users that you'd be working with.

Wanting to know more I hovered over the ad, only to find that there aren't multiple elements I can click on, just one single mega-link, which only remind me of those dodgy adverts that solicit clicking on what seem like interactive elements (text fields etc) but are just a giant link off somewhere nasty.

Why is this set up this way? Can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: "dodgy adverts that solicit clicking on what seem like interactive elements (text fields etc) but are just a giant link off somewhere nasty" Or, more playfully: http://www.pagetutor.com/idiot/idiot.html (requires Java)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's just the way these ads are setup for now. They're meant to showcase companies, so the link gets you to a page with all sorts of info on the company. From that page, you can see the people who work at that company (and are on stack overflow, and are linked to the company), as well as jobs the company has, details about benefits, details about the technologies of the company etc.

We're investigating changes to them, so people are able to click on individual jobs, people etc.

---

Update 2017/09/07: we decided to style the text so it doesn't look like a link anymore.

Comment: +1 for the explanation; -1 for the monolithic approach in the first place; +1 for looking to fix it.  Net: +1

Comment: @kjhughes +1 for the detail; -1 for the length; +1 for the humour. Net: +1